# display name by id at controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How to display name in list by it's id. code as follows.

```
$allocationIds = $this->Staff->StaffAllocation->find('list',array(
                         'fields'=>array('StaffAllocation.group_id' ), 
                         'conditions'=>$conditions));
```

here output comes

```
Array
(
    [7] => 5
)
```

here `5` is group id as come from field assign

`'fields'=>array('StaffAllocation.group_id' ),`

here we need

```
Array
(
    [7] => group name
)
```

as we have relation with group table with `StaffAllocation`

Comment: Post your `Staff` and `StaffAllocation` model associations. `group_id` should be referring to a `Group` model, so post that s well. `Staff belongsTo Group` and `Group hasMany Staff` would be one possible setup.

Comment: yes we have these relation with Staff , StaffAllocation  and Group. while debug($allocationIds) output as above . we required group name from this id 5

Comment: could you give a output for debug($allocationIDs) with a find all?

Comment: above mention Array
(
    [7] => group name
)